# kill app in a given timeframe, bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, kill

I'm new at bash and I am trying to make this, here is a pseudo code:

```
id= "pidof rhytmbox" (rhytmbox changes pid everytime i start it)

echo "Input time: "
read time

sleep $time
kill $pid
```

can you assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to run your command with a time limit you can make use of timeout:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p \
    "Input time in minutes: " duration

[[ ! $duration =~ [^0-9] ]] && \
    timeout ${duration}m setsid rhytmbox &>/dev/null &
```

`read` has a prompt option which is shown before attempting to read an input. You can use a regex statement to ensure user input only contain digits. Now, I usually want to put *long-running* application in the background in case I close the terminal, you can accomplish this with `setsid` command `&`

Answer (score 1):

```
pid=$(pidof rhythmbox)
echo $pid

echo "Enter time: "
read time
sleep $time
kill $pid
```

This one worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide some hints.

Bash has some ways to assign the output of a command to a variable.

```
pid=$(pidof top)
pid=`pidof top`
```

For the rest you're basically on the right track. You should probably [validate that the user is in fact entering a integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806923/11529761), and not some other text such as `half an hour`.

Comment: thank you
---

pid=$(pidof rhythmbox)
echo $pid

echo "Enter time: "
read time
sleep $time
kill $pid

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark on the left. If you get new and better answers, you can change your accepted answer at any time.